# How to create a patch file (SVN) in a Mac?

Tags: svn, macos, versions

i'm helping out a friend who has a Mac and has installed Versions, but apparently there doesnt seem to be a way to create a patch file. I saw the screenshots he sent to me and it appeared that it was correct.

Anyone used Versions on Mac for doing SVN and if so, were they able to create patches which could be shared wiht others on Windows / other platforms?

Is there a better software to use other than Versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is commercial software, so your friend could fire off a question to the support center.

But on their FAQ it says:

> Q: How can I use Versions to merge?
>
> A:  Right now, there's no way to merge changes between branches in Versions.

So maybe they really do not have the more "advanced" features (if you can call patching and merging advanced).

There is [a list of other SVN clients for Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449/is-there-a-good-gui-svn-app-for-mac-better-than-xcode) here on Stackoverflow. The good thing is that they all use the standard subversion way of storing data, so you should be able to mix and match. You could for example use the command line to create a patch, and continue using Versions for everything else.

Eclipse or Netbeans or any other IDE does it, too.

Comment: (horrified - so there's no free/open-source svn client on the Mac?) Just needed to create a basic patch file!

Comment: @Frank You (or your friend) are always welcome to develop a free/open-source Subversion client for Mac OS!

Answer (score 1):

He can just open up Terminal.app and use the command line `svn` client.

Comment: wow, so there's no gui way of doing thais on a mac? feel blessed as a windows user... ;)

Comment: @Frank: well, didn't say that, I just pointed out the obvious fallback. I personally use Eclipse on my MacBook, which has good svn support (two different implementations, actually!)